# Xamarin Don't work push notification

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android

I'm new in Xamarin. I try do [this app](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/), but on this [step](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/#Handle_Notification_Intents) `Intent.Extras = null`

Code:

```
            Log.Debug(TAG, "Intent.Extras: " + (Intent.Extras == null));
            if (Intent.Extras != null)
            {
                Log.Debug(TAG, "I am before foreach");
                foreach (var key in Intent.Extras.KeySet())
                {
                    var value = Intent.Extras.GetString(key);
                    Log.Debug(TAG, "Key: {0} Value: {1}", key, value);
                }
            }
            IsPlayServicesAvailable();
```

Log.debug send in console:

> D/MainActivity: Intent.Extras: True

Why is Intent.Extras = null?

Comment: Could you please post your code about `notification builder`?

Comment: I don't use 'notification builder'. Notification delivered without builder. Look here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/#Send_a_Message

Comment: When your app receive the message, your app will send a local Notification in your `FirebaseMessagingService`, here is the [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/#Add_a_Local_Notifications_Sender).